# ssdt dacpac: how to structure diffrent versions

Tags: sql-server-data-tools, dacpac

Two sql scripts (update/rollback) are created for each version in current projects. We would like to migrate to DACPAC solution.

Each DACPAC project creates 1 file dacpac at the en so for each version, I create 2 project (1 for update and 1 for rollback). The schema changes will be in dacpac itself while pre-script and post-script are for data migration.

To add a new version, I copy the current update project into new update project and new rollback project. Then modify from there.

Any thoughts please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this comes down to whether you need to actually do all this work, the way I work with SSDT is to define what I want the current version to look like in the schema + code and any upgrade scripts I need go into the post-deploy files as re-runnable scripts (idempotent).

If a db is on version 1 or 100 they still get the same post-deploy script but either the script checks for the data or a flag that is stored in the database to say that particular script has already been run - that should be pretty easy to setup but depends on your exact requirements.

To keep this manageable it is a good idea to know when particular scripts have gone to all of your environments and then remove them so you only actually have the post-deploy scripts that you are ever going to actually need.

That being said, there are sometimes specific restrictions which are normally:

- Customers managing databases so you can't be sure what version they have
- Regulatory (perceived or otherwise) requirements demanding upgrade/rollback scripts

Firstly find out how set in stone your requirements are, the goal of SSDT is to not have to worry about upgrade / downgrade scripts (certainly for the schema) - the questions I would ask are:

- is it enough to take a backup or snapshot before the deploy?
- can you leave off downgrade scripts and write them should you ever need to?
- how often are the rollback scripts ever used (also knowing the first two can help here)

If you have a good suite of tests, an automated deployment pipeline (even if it has a manual DBA step in at some point) then these issues become less important and over time as everyone learns to trust the process can become significantly faster and easier to deploy changes.

What are your restrictions?

Ed

Comment: Thanks Ed. "If a db is on version 1 or 100 they still get the same post-deploy script but either the script checks for the data or a flag that is stored in the database to say that particular script has already been run - that should be pretty easy to setup but depends on your exact requirements." it is exactly what i want but dont know what is the best practice. From your explanation, looks like i need to manage 1 SSDT project and do versioning the code inside pre/post scripts with regarding to the current version on target db. Can you share me an a brief example of how you have done?

Comment: Sure, I think the easiest is to use a "versions_deployed" table which includes a version identifier and a date so your upgrade script becomes (if not exist(select * from versions_deployed where name = id) begin blah insert into versions_deployed id) - if you put each version upgrade in it's own script and reference it from the post-deploy script using ":r filename" then it is simpler to see what you have in solution explorer - this also tracks when things were deployed which is nice for some scenarios.

Comment: Given 3 versions: v1(pre1, schema1, post1), v2, v3. Your solution  is (pre1 pre2 pre3, schema, post1 post2 post3). It works well If the pres are not depending on previous post. However if post1 insert new row, pre2 modifies, then post2 moves somewhere else. Any thoughts?

Comment: What are you doing that requires complicated migration scripts? How drastically is stuff changing between versions?

Comment: in v1 post-script, insert few more rows. then in v2, i'd like to refactor 1 table into 3 tables (2 ref tables and 1 detail table). At the pre-script, the original table will be copied to temp table. then dacpac will create 3 tables and delete old one. at the post-script, the data will be filled from temp table. in v3, again insert few rows to new tables.

Comment: ok, quick q -why don't you know when changes have been applied to all environments. If you complete a piece of work on monday, when is that deployed to production, assuming friday, why can't you take the pre/post deploy scripts out the following monday?

Comment: it is just an example of data-related pre/post-scripts. the changes are uncontrolled by us and are depending on the client with few month interval.

Comment: ok, as long as you test that your data is in the state you expect it to in each of the pre/post deploy scripts (either by using a releases table and/or checking the data) then you should be able to do it and checking for whether you should do it will make everyone's life easier - non-re-runnable scripts are a nightmare for everyone (except maybe readyroll users :) ). *But* take a step back and decide whether you want small incremental releases or batched releases - if batched releases then work with that and have 1 upgrade script for each release + deploy dacpacs in specific order for each ver

Comment: My workaround: use your suggestion of incremental post-scripts (the same project/same dacpac) until pre-post is required. Then clone to new project, implement pre-script, and continue incremental post-scripts... The fact that pre-scripts are very little comparing to incremental post-scripts, the number of dacpac projects will be acceptable. Any comments pls?

Comment: sounds like a good workaround to deal with the uncertainty of when things will be deployed! The more normal thing is to have a single project and to tag or mark the source control when you change version rather than cloning into new project but do what works best for you!

Comment: thanks Ed. let me convert 1 whole project to see if it handle all or not.

Answer (score 2):

If you find that you're investing a fair amount of effort putting logic into a post-deployment script, the chances are that a migrations-based approach (and not the state-based approach) is more suited for you.

Examples are [DBUp](https://dbup.github.io/) (open source), [ReadyRoll](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/readyroll/) (this is commercial and the one we develop here at Redgate - has additional features such as auto-generation of scripts integration with VS etc).

Migrations-based tools manage the versions (including the table Ed is referring to) on your behalf.

Comment: thanks David. need to convine the boss that ssdt is not suitable before testing on others :)

Comment: Fair enough. But do let us know if you have any questions, particularly when you hit further limitations of SSDT's database project.